# location of tasks.vs.json ignored by vs recommended .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, ide, gitignore, ignore

In every .gitignore template for Visual studio (e.g. [Here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore))
the `.vs` cache directory is marked as **to ignore**.

but when i create a Task (right click on solution explorer >> Configure tasks), it create a file named `tasks.vs.json` inside the `.vs` folder!

I noticed I can move the file out of that directory and have the tasks available, but still 'Configure Tasks' will create a new file inside `.vs`!

I know I can "un-ignore" specific files in GitIgnore, thats an option, but I seek a cleaner way.

So my questions are:

1. Can I tell VS that my Task.vs.json belong outside `.vs` folder?
2. Did MS intend the Tasks to be user specific ? (unlikely)

Comment: Regardless of how you do this, note that Git will merge json files line-by-line, which is wrong for json files (though often not quite as bad as it tends to be for XML files). Yaml files can have similar problems but these are rarer for yaml.

Comment: @torek you incline that there is an alternative to Tasks.vs.json  something like Tasks.vs.yaml?

Comment: No, it's just a general thought about being aware of mis-merges.